# Hibernate: When to use getSession() and when to use getCurrentSession()?

Tags: hibernate

I have been using hibernate with Springs where i don't get to use getSession() or getCurrentSession() as the Spring container manages it.

But i came across this getSession() and getCurrentSession() methods while reading hibernate.

Can anyone explain when to use either of the methods?

Answer (score 2):

[getCurrentSession](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29) is a method of the SessionFactory interface. As the name implies, an implementation of this method is responsible for creating and managing sessions. What does "current" mean, depends on the implementation.

A getSession method is usually used by classes that build wrappers around Hibernate (like Spring's [HibernateDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html)).

I don't think that there is a class that implements both of these methods. You can't compare them outside of the context they are used and the classes that implement them.